# Copy a Javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I would like to copy a Javascript datepicker (calender) from one app to another. But I could not do that. If i save the original app page(the site from where I would like to copy) the datepicker is not working (peculiar). Even I copy pasete the html and css code also but I am not getting the javascript datepicker. What can be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the page source. Download necessory `.js` files, `.css` files into your folder / directory. Also copy relevant JavaScript, CSS and HTML from the page. Then compile another html file in that directory using downloaded files and copied scrips. This should work.